# transfer js var without php

Tags: javascript, jquery, variables

in **index.html** background is changing randomly when you open it

```
var imgArr=['background.jpg', 'backgrounds2.jpg', 'backgrounds3.jpg'];
i=Math.round(Math.random()*2);
$('.wrap').css({'background': 'url('+imgArr[i]+') no-repeat fixed'});
```

in other pages i don't need to change background but use one from index.html
 how can i save one var value from index.html and use it in other pages without changing?

Comment: use cookies to store data across requests/pages

Comment: Cookies or URL-parameters like `http://.../index.html?myVar=123` are simple, traditional ways of providing parameters to pages, but it's a bit unclear what you're really trying to do and if this is suitable or there are better solutions to your issue.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use cookies or `localStorage` or even better `sessionStorage`.

```
var imgArr=['background.jpg', 'backgrounds2.jpg', 'backgrounds3.jpg'];
i = Math.floor(Math.random() * imgArr.length);
//fewer harcoded values is better :-)
$('.wrap').css({'background': 'url('+imgArr[i]+') no-repeat fixed'});
sessionStorage.setItem("bg", imgArr[i]);
```

Of course you should check if storage is available before attempting to access it, but it will be available in modern browsers.

Comment: wow great! modern web technologies its realy cool, thank u very much!

Answer (score 0):

The easiest way would be to jsut set a default in the CSS - your JS would then override that on index.html, and if you omit the js from the other pages then it will revert to the default.

You could also use JS to set a cookie and then read from that but then youd still need to plan for if someone accesses page without having the cookie set, so id probably go with the CSS option were I you.

Comment: yes but i need use result from index.html in other pages. well.. code can be in one external file

Comment: @RomanPerfilyev: In that case youll need to use the cookie, or pass it along with a get parameter and then parse that from the URL.

Answer (score 0):

If you are using any server side language then try SESSION to store the value. 
If you are using only client-side language then try using cookie or pass the value through parameter to the next page.

Answer (score 0):

You can add some element to index.html and check in your javascript if it exists it will mean that you are on index.html page and you should change background. For example add

```
<div id="iamindex"></div>
```

And you javascript:

```
if($('#iamindex').length) {
  var imgArr=['background.jpg', 'backgrounds2.jpg', 'backgrounds3.jpg'];
  i=Math.round(Math.random()*2);
  $('.wrap').css({'background': 'url('+imgArr[i]+') no-repeat fixed'});
}
```